# C++ to C Wrapper using SWIG (for FLTK)

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, swig, fltk

I need to generate wrapper to FLTK C++ classes to use it in pure C.
I know, that SWIG can do that, and I know how to generate wrapper for C#, Python etc.
But I do not know how to wrap C++ to C using SWIG.
It's simple task, but I can't find the answer :) Please, help.

Comment: Interesting, from what I can tell from the documentation, SWIG generates C wrappers for C++ code, it should be possible to use those directly

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find in documentation information on how to do that. I will continue searching...

Comment: @Hasturkun: I think you are misinterpreting the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think SWIG supports generation of C wrappers out of the box. You always need to specify a target language. In 2008, there was a [GSoC project](http://www.dabeaz.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?GSoCCBackend) to write a [C backend](http://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2008-swig/downloads/detail?name=Maciej_Drwal.tar.gz&can=2&q=), but that was apparently never completed/incorporated into SWIG.

Comment: I don't think this documentation is meant to be taken literal. Instead, this illustrates how the wrapper functions for each language look like. Instead of `new_list`, the Python generator (for example) generates `_wrap_new_List`; this becomes available to Python as `new_List`. `_wrap_new_List` does more than the documentation says, as it also needs to integrate with the Python VM.

Comment: Now I testing SWIG with C backend. Compiled It successfully with mingw, but got some errors while parsing FLTK includes (Such: FLTK13\FL\filename.h(60): Error: Syntax error in input(1).). I will report results... Thanks for idea!

Comment: I decided to go another way to solve my problem, but for problem described in question above, solution that Martin offered - the best solution, that can be found. Thank you again.

Comment: Yo can download SWIG with C backend from svn (https://swig.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/swig/branches/gsoc2008-maciekd/). It best compiled with mingw+msys (use automated installer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/) with such commands: ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make. Use swig in such way: `swig -c++ -c  fltk13.i`

Comment: There was a [gsoc2012](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/gsoc2012-c) not yet finished but closer.